# Creating centile charts in R

Tags: r, plot, percentile

I am working on some visualizations, and I want to produce a centile plot. I want to do something similar to the classic height / weight chart:

[image]

I found that the 'lmsqreq' package might be appropriate to help in creating these, however, it appears to be old and not supported anymore:

```
install.packages("lmsqreg")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘lmsqreg’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

My question is, has anyone either coded up these plots themselves or has anyone found a package that might assist?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical approach that will generate these smooth lines from data?  Or do you have the line data already and you are just looking for a way to plot it?

Comment: The former, of course, would be the ideal situation. But if such a package doesn't exist, the latter would be the next best scenario.

Comment: How about the `lms` function in the `gamlss` package.